# Unusual boot behavior (16.04)

Tags: boot, 16.04

Whilst starting up Ubuntu 16.04 I always encounter the same set of issues..

**First Attempt:**

I'll hit the power button, after hitting 'Ubuntu' from GRUB.

**Second Attempt:**

Once again make it past the BIOS then we'll hit the decrypt key phase; the keyboard, and any other USB devices will become completely unresponsive as if they've been disconnected.

The only way I may actually startup the computer is by entering recovery mode. When I'm finally logged in certain things such as wallpaper, and desktop items are reset. Any ideas?